# Why is the set $K$ recursively enumerable?

Tags: combinatorics, computability, recursion, turing-machines

I am trying to understand why the set $K=\{i \mid M_i(i) \;\mathsf{halts}\}$ is recursively enumerable, where $M_i(i)$ is a Turing machine that is given its own index (in the standard enumeration of Turing machines) as input ("the halting problem").

If we cannot determine if $M_i(i)$ halts, how could we even produce the set $K$ in the first place? If $K$ were recursively enumerable, we could have a Turing machine $M_K$ that takes this set as input and outputs a list of all of its elements. But if this were the case, the halting problem would be solvable because of the fact that all of the elements of $K$ are known in the first place.

I am obviously missing a big point here. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what "recursively enumerable" means. If taking the set as input were allowed, then *everything* would be recursively enumerable (or nothing noncomputable would be, if you require the input the be computed first) because given a set $X$ as input, enumerating its members is as simple as reading them off.

A set $S$ is *recursively enumerable* if there is a Turing machine $M_S$ which, given *no* input, lists out the members of $S$. In this case, the halting set can be enumerated by the following process:

At stage $0$, start $M_0$ running on input $0$.

At any stage $s > 0$, start $M_s$ running on input $s$, and advance each machine started at an earlier stage by one step. If there is an $M_i$ for $i < s$ so that $M_i$ just now halted, output $i$.

This process enumerates the members of $K$, in no particular order. It's still difficult to tell whether a *given* $n$ is in $K$; if it is, it'll eventually show up, but if it isn't we'll never be sure of that.

Answer (score 4):

Just because you have a machine that outputs the elements of $K$ doesn't mean they "are all known".

The problem is that $M_K$ does not necessarily output the elements *in order*, so just observing the run of that machine will never allow you to conclude that some number is *not* in $K$. You can fun the machine for a year and notice that your favorite number has not *yet* been output, but you can't know whether it will be output next week, or in another year, or a century -- or, indeed, never at all.

This is THE difference between "decidable" and "recursively enumerable".